# Implement RealmModel while extending AbstractItem

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, fastadapter

I was using `FastAdapter` cause it's fun and relieves me from writing adapter classes. Here is a class:

```
public class ProductsModel extends AbstractItem<ProductsModel, ProductsModel.ViewHolder> {
```

But recently I want to use `Realm` instead of `SQLite`. So I wanted to do this:

```
public class ProductsModel extends AbstractItem<ProductsModel, ProductsModel.ViewHolder> implements RealmModel {
```

And before any transaction I was doing this:

```
RealmResults<ProductsModel> productsModels = realm.where(ProductsModel.class).findAll(); // <- this line is generating the exception
if(productsModels.size() == 0){ //no product is saved, download now

}
```

But getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AbstractItem is not part of the schema for this Realm
```

Please tell me how can I use Realm with FastAdapter.

Comment: I still use Realm and FastAdapter, but as your code above `ProductsModel` is not a Model in Realm, it 's a **Item** representing for the item in adapter. so it cannot `implements RealmModel`. It 's just Item, you need to follow example of fastadapter to do it.

Comment: Thanks, can you please share any example/tutorial? I did not get [this](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/tree/develop/library-extensions-realm)

Comment: You can get it from https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/tree/develop/app. Just get all and build it.

Comment: Okay, seeing `RealmSampleUserItem`. I think that'll work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you can not extend the `AbstractItem` the `FastAdapter` allows you to simply implement the `IItem` interface. You will have to implement the functions you already know + the ones which would normally be implemented by the `AbstractItem`

Here is a sample item:

```
public class SampleRealmItem extends RealmObject implements IItem<SampleRealmItem, SampleRealmItem.ViewHolder> {
    // the identifier for this item
    @PrimaryKey
    protected long mIdentifier = -1;

    @Override
    public long getIdentifier() {
        return mIdentifier;
    }

    // the tag for this item
    @Ignore
    protected Object mTag;

    @Override
    public Object getTag() {
        return mTag;
    }

    // defines if this item is enabled
    @Ignore
    protected boolean mEnabled = true;

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return mEnabled;
    }

    // defines if the item is selected
    @Ignore
    protected boolean mSelected = false;

    @Override
    public SampleRealmItem withSetSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.mSelected = selected;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return mSelected;
    }

    // defines if this item is selectable
    @Ignore
    protected boolean mSelectable = true;

    @Override
    public SampleRealmItem withSelectable(boolean selectable) {
        this.mSelectable = selectable;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelectable() {
        return mSelectable;
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return R.id.some_id;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.some_layout;
    }

    @Override
    public View generateView(Context ctx) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = getViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(getLayoutRes(), null, false));
        //as we already know the type of our ViewHolder cast it to our type
        bindView(viewHolder, Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
        //return the bound view
        return viewHolder.itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public View generateView(Context ctx, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = getViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(getLayoutRes(), parent, false));
        //as we already know the type of our ViewHolder cast it to our type
        bindView(viewHolder, Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
        //return the bound and generatedView
        return viewHolder.itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder getViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        return getViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(getLayoutRes(), parent, false));
    }

    private ViewHolder getViewHolder(View v) {
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(ViewHolder holder, List<Object> payloads) {
        //set the selected state of this item. force this otherwise it may is missed when implementing an item
        holder.itemView.setSelected(isSelected());
        //set the tag of this item to this object (can be used when retrieving the view)
        holder.itemView.setTag(this);

        //handle your binding
    }

    @Override
    public void unbindView(ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.name.setText(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void attachToWindow(ViewHolder holder) {}

    @Override
    public void detachFromWindow(ViewHolder holder) {}

    @Override
    public boolean failedToRecycle(ViewHolder holder) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(int id) {
        return id == mIdentifier;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        AbstractItem<?, ?> that = (AbstractItem<?, ?>) o;
        return mIdentifier == that.getIdentifier();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Long.valueOf(mIdentifier).hashCode();
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }
    }
}
```

To simplify it, I have removed comments, and unnecessary setters. A full sample can be found in the `FastAdapter`s sample source here:
https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/app/items/RealmSampleUserItem.java

In case you are interested, here you can find the default `AbstractItem` implementation:
https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/develop/library-core/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/items/AbstractItem.java

Comment: Cannot implement `OnClick`. Can you please have a look at [here](https://gist.github.com/tariqul-islam1/afbea341923d2c550f922194607513e3) and tell me what am I missing?

Comment: I do not really understand what you are trying to do. The Model does not have the listener. you can attach one to the FastAdapter

Comment: Can you please have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364540/implement-onclicklistener-on-fastadapter-implementing-iitem)?